# Se me reinicia un servicio despues de cerrar el app

Tags: android, android-studio, servicio

Tengo un servicio que se conecta a una base de datos cada 10 segundos para verificar la existencia de cierto dato, si existe envia una notificacion al usuario. todo funciona correctamente. Pero cuando cierro el app, el servicio se reinicia y vuelve a mostrar  la ultima notificación,(mostrando dos veces la ultima notificacion). Para simplificar el asunto decidí modificar el servicio para que me muestre un conteo, que se visualiza por un TOAST. Entonces ejecuto el APP, empieza el conteo y por ejemplo cierro la aplicación cuando el conteo va en 5, y este se reinicia y comienza de nuevo desde cero.

En resumidas cuentas, cada vez que se cierra el APP, se reinicia mi servicio.

```
public class MiServicio extends Service {
NotificationManager notificationManager;




@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {

    notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE); 
    super.onCreate();


}
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {


    final long vibra[] ={0,100,100};
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    TimerTask task3 = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try{
                        //tualiza_mis_preferencias(); // las lee desde base de datos
                        //s_preferencias(); // las lee desde sharedpreferences para la app
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), String.valueOf(infinito),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        infinito++;
                        //Log.i(TAG,infinito);
                    }catch (EmptyStackException e){
                        Log.e("error", e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    };

/*

    TimerTask doAsynchronousTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            final SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("AutomataSP", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

            final String cadena = "";

            final String mialerta_leidaSP = preferencias.getString("miAlerta_leida", "no hay dato");
            handler.post(new Runnable()
            {
                public void run() {

                    url2 = "http://190.xxx.xxx.xxx:80/regresa_alarmas.php";
                    parametros2 = "?eid_comu=" + comu  + "&eid_alerta=" + mialerta_leidaSP;
                    //Log.i(TAG,parametros2);
                    OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
                    request = new Request.Builder().url(url2+parametros2).build();

                    /// ejecutamos el request
                    client.newCall(request).enqueue(new Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(Call call, IOException e) {
                            Log.i(TAG, e.getMessage());
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(Call call, Response response) throws IOException {
                            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferencias.edit();
                            alert = alert + 1;
                            respuesta2 = response.body().string(); // tomo la respuesta del webservice JSON y la transformo a string
                            //Log.i(TAG,respuesta2);
                            //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),response.body().string(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            if (respuesta2.contains("nomensajes")){
                                Log.i(TAG,"Sin alertas nuevas");
                                //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sin notificaciones",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }else{
                                try{
                                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(respuesta2);
                                    malerta_leida = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("id_alerta");
                                    mmnombre = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("nombre");
                                    mtipo_alerta = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("tipo_alerta");
                                    mmapellido = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getString("apellidos");
                                    Log.i(TAG, malerta_leida);
                                    if (mtipo_alerta.contains("1")){
                                        cadena_alerta = "Robo";
                                    }
                                    if (mtipo_alerta.contains("2")){
                                        cadena_alerta = "Panico";
                                    }
                                    if (mtipo_alerta.contains("3")){
                                        cadena_alerta = "Incendio";
                                    }
                                    if (mtipo_alerta.contains("4")){
                                        cadena_alerta = "Emergencia";
                                    }
                                }catch (JSONException e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }catch (Exception e){
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                //Log.d(TAG, "onResponse: ");
                                // si la alerta leida es distinta a la almacenada anteriormente
                                NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getBaseContext())
                                        .setSmallIcon(R.raw.ic_noti_32)
                                        .setContentTitle("Sistema de alertas  - Alarmas Comunitarias ")
                                        .setContentText(mmnombre + " " + mmapellido + "   -   " + cadena_alerta)
                                        .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX)
                                        .setVibrate(vibra)
                                        .setLights(Color.CYAN, 1, 0)

                                        .setSound(RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM))
                                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

                                /*
                                //activity que se lanza al hacer click en la notificacion
                                Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ePrincipal.class);

                                //
                                PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),0,resultIntent,0);
                                //establece el comportamientl del click de la notificacion
                                builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);


                                notificationManager.notify(ID_NOTI,builder.build());
                            }
                            editor.putString("miAlerta_leida", malerta_leida);
                            editor.commit();
                            //Log.i(TAG,"alerta leida y registrada");
                            //////fin noti builder
                        }///fin Onresponse
                    });
                }///fin run
            }

            );
        }
    };
    */
    //timer.schedule(doAsynchronousTask, 0, 10000); //execute in every 10000 ms
    timer.schedule(task3,0,3000);

    return START_STICKY;
}//TERMINA onSTARTCOMMAND
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Primeramente comentaré para que sirve la propiedad **START_STICKY** :

> **Service.START_STICKY** : recrea el servicio si la aplicación se
>   destruye.

Es por esta razón que tu servicio inicia nuevamente después de cerrar la aplicación:

```
 @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        ...
        ...
        return START_STICKY;
    }
```

Desgraciadamente al cerrar (destruir) la aplicación, se detendrá momentáneamente el servicio y posteriormente iniciara nuevamente.

Comment: Si entiendo eso, disculpa quizas me exprese erroneamente, Quisiera que mi servicio siga funcionando despues de cerrar la aplicacion sin que se reinicie.

Comment: @R.S. en realidad el servicio va a tener que detenerse por un momento, pero iniciarà nuevamente. No creo que pueda mantenerse ya que depende del ciclo de vida de la aplicación que lo inicio :-(