# onLocationChanged() no funciona en las ultimas versiones de android en modo screen off

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, geolocalización, real-time

necesito ayuda con un problema que encontré en una aplicación que hice, ya busque en todas partes y no encontré una solución. Espero que ustedes puedan ayudarme. Hice una aplicación que toma la localización del usuario y usando el método onLocationChanged() va enviando esa ubicación a firebase, la cuestión es que cuando la probé en distintas versiones de android encontré que en las ultimas versiones cuando apago la pantalla del teléfono o me salgo de la aplicación sin cerrarla, la ubicación deja de enviarse a firebase cosa que no sucede en versiones de android mas antiguas.
No sé que es lo que estoy pasando por alto, y me gustaría saber si alguien se ha encontrado con un problema similar y como lo ha solucionado, me sería de mucha ayuda leer sus opiniones...

les dejaré la parte de código que uso para enviar la ubicación a firebase.

(Uso GeoFire para insertar la latitud y longitud en la base de datos de firebase)

```java
  @Override 
  public void onLocationChanged(Location location){
      if(getContext()) != null){

          mLastLocation = location;
          LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), 
          location.getLongitude());

          mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
          mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(16));

          final DatabaseReference refAvalible = FirebaseDatabase
          .getInstance().getReference().child("Activos");

          final DatabaseReference refOcup = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("ocupados");

          if(!userId.equals(null)){

              if(Preferences.obtenerPreferenceBoolean(getContext(), Preferences.PREFERENCE_DISPONIBLE)){

                  DatabaseReference servicio = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child("userTypeOne").child(userId).child("serviceId");

                   servicio.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

                       if(datasnapshot.exists()){

                           GeoFire geoFireDisponible = new Geofire(refAvalible);
                           GeoFire geoFireOcupado = new GeoFire(refOcup);

                           geoFireAvalible.removeLocation(userId);
                           geoFireOcupado.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude, mLastLocation.getLongitude());
                       }
                       else{

                           GeoFire geoFireDisponible = new Geofire(refAvalible);
                           GeoFire geoFireOcupado = new GeoFire(refOcup);


                           geoFireOcupado.removeLocation(userId);
                           geoFireDisponible.setLocation(userId, new GeoLocation(mLastLocation.getLatitude(), mLastLocation.getLongitude()));                       


                       }

              }

          }



      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Los limites de ejecución en segundo plano](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html?hl=es) han cambiado para las aplicaciones con sistema operativo Android Oreo 8.0 (API 26) o posterior.

Lo que debes realizar es un servicio que tenga definido [START_STICKY](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/110062/se-me-reinicia-un-servicio-despues-de-cerrar-el-app/110163#110163) para que recree tu servicio aunque la aplicación sea cerrada.

```
  @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
          ...
          ...
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }
```

Si estas usando GeoFire, puedes revisar esta respuesta en el sitio en inglés que contiene precisamente un ejemplo de lo que deseas:

[How to add background service in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50306777/how-to-add-background-service-in-geofence-android)

Revisa la clase ejemplo creada por Vinayak D:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {


    private GoogleMap mMap;
    //Play Service Location
    private static final int MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 7192;
    private static final int PLAY_SERVICE_RESULATION_REQUEST = 300193;

    private Location mLastLocaiton;

    private static int UPDATE_INTERVAL = 5000;
    private static int FATEST_INTERVAL = 3000;
    private static int DISPLACEMENT = 10;


    Marker mCurrent;
    VerticalSeekBar mVerticalSeekBar;
    private static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private GeoService geoService;
    private boolean serviceBound;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.



        mVerticalSeekBar = (VerticalSeekBar) findViewById(R.id.verticalSeekBar);
        mVerticalSeekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(progress), 1500, null);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });



    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE:
                if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (checkPlayService()) {
                        geoService.buildGoogleApiClient();
                        geoService.createLocationRequest();
                        geoService.displayLocation();
                        geoService.setLocationChangeListener(new GeoService.LocationChangeListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
                                if (mCurrent != null)
                                    mCurrent.remove();
                                mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                        .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                                        .title("You"));
                                LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                                CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
                                mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void setUpdateLocation() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
                    Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
            }, MY_PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            if (checkPlayService()) {
                geoService.buildGoogleApiClient();
                geoService.createLocationRequest();
                geoService.displayLocation();
                geoService.setLocationChangeListener(new GeoService.LocationChangeListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onLocationChange(Location location) {
                        if (mCurrent != null)
                            mCurrent.remove();
                        mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                                .position(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()))
                                .title("You"));
                        LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                        CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
                        mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }


    private boolean checkPlayService() {
        GoogleApiAvailability googleAPI = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();
        int result = googleAPI.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
        if (result != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (googleAPI.isUserResolvableError(result)) {
                googleAPI.getErrorDialog(this, result, PLAY_SERVICE_RESULATION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "This Device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        LatLng dangerous_area = new LatLng(8.5324236, 76.8842189);
        mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                .center(dangerous_area)
                .radius(2000)
                .strokeColor(Color.BLUE)
                .fillColor(0x220000FF)
                .strokeWidth(5.0f));

        geoService.startService(dangerous_area,2000);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
            Log.v(TAG, "Starting and binding service");
        }
        Intent i = new Intent(this, GeoService.class);
        startService(i);
        bindService(i, mConnection, 0);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (serviceBound) {
            // If a timer is active, foreground the service, otherwise kill the service
            if (geoService.isServiceRunning()) {
                geoService.foreground();
            } else {
                stopService(new Intent(this, GeoService.class));
            }
            // Unbind the service
            unbindService(mConnection);
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback for service binding, passed to bindService()
     */
    private ServiceConnection mConnection = new ServiceConnection() {

        @Override
        public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName className, IBinder service) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Service bound");
            }
            GeoService.RunServiceBinder binder = (GeoService.RunServiceBinder) service;
            geoService = binder.getService();
            serviceBound = true;
            // Ensure the service is not in the foreground when bound
            geoService.background();
            setUpdateLocation();
            SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
            mapFragment.getMapAsync(MapsActivity.this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName name) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Service disconnect");
            }
            serviceBound = false;
        }
    };


    public static class GeoService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
            GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
            LocationListener {
        private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
        private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
        private Location mLastLocation;
        private DatabaseReference ref;
        private GeoFire geoFire;
        private LocationChangeListener mLocationChangeListener;
        private static final String TAG = GeoService.class.getSimpleName();


        // Is the service tracking time?
        private boolean isServiceRunning;

        // Foreground notification id
        private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

        // Service binder
        private final IBinder serviceBinder = new RunServiceBinder();
        private GeoQuery geoQuery;

        public class RunServiceBinder extends Binder {
            GeoService getService() {
                return GeoService.this;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Creating service");
            }
            ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("MyLocation");
            geoFire = new GeoFire(ref);
            isServiceRunning = false;
        }

        @Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Starting service");
            }
            return Service.START_STICKY;
        }

        @Override
        public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Binding service");
            }
            return serviceBinder;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            if (Log.isLoggable(TAG, Log.VERBOSE)) {
                Log.v(TAG, "Destroying service");
            }
        }

        /**
         * Starts the timer
         */
        public void startService(LatLng latLng, double radius) {
            if (!isServiceRunning) {
                isServiceRunning = true;

            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "startService request for an already running Service");

            }
            if (geoQuery!=null){
                geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
            }
            geoQuery = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(latLng.latitude, latLng.longitude), 2f);
            geoQuery.addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s entered the dangerous area", key));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    sendNotification("MRF", String.format("%s exit the dangerous area", key));
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", "" + error);
                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Stops the timer
         */
        public void stopService() {
            if (isServiceRunning) {
                isServiceRunning = false;
                geoQuery.removeAllListeners();
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "stopTimer request for a timer that isn't running");
            }
        }

        /**
         * @return whether the service is running
         */
        public boolean isServiceRunning() {
            return isServiceRunning;
        }


        /**
         * Place the service into the foreground
         */
        public void foreground() {
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, createNotification());
        }

        /**
         * Return the service to the background
         */
        public void background() {
            stopForeground(true);
        }

        /**
         * Creates a notification for placing the service into the foreground
         *
         * @return a notification for interacting with the service when in the foreground
         */
        private Notification createNotification() {
            NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("Service is Active")
                    .setContentText("Tap to return to the Map")
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);

            Intent resultIntent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            PendingIntent resultPendingIntent =
                    PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, resultIntent,
                            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
            builder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

            return builder.build();
        }

        private void sendNotification(String title, String content) {
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content);

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);
            PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);
            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
            Notification notification = builder.build();
            notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            manager.notify(new Random().nextInt(), notification);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
            displayLocation();
            startLocationUpdate();
        }

        private void startLocationUpdate() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            mLastLocation = location;
            displayLocation();
        }

        interface LocationChangeListener {
            void onLocationChange(Location location);
        }

        private void createLocationRequest() {
            mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FATEST_INTERVAL);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            mLocationRequest.setSmallestDisplacement(DISPLACEMENT);
        }

        private void buildGoogleApiClient() {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API).build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }

        private void displayLocation() {
            if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                    ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                return;
            }

            mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
            if (mLastLocation != null) {
                final double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
                final double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

                geoFire.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
                        if (mLocationChangeListener!=null) {
                            mLocationChangeListener.onLocationChange(mLastLocation);
                        }
                    }
                });

                Log.d("MRF", String.format("Your last location was chaged: %f / %f", latitude, longitude));
            } else {
                Log.d("MRF", "Can not get your location.");
            }
        }

        public void setLocationChangeListener(LocationChangeListener mLocationChangeListener) {
            this.mLocationChangeListener = mLocationChangeListener;
        }
    }

}
```

No olvidar declarar el servicio en tu `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
 <service android:name=".MapsActivity$GeoService" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Lo que esta pasando es que en las versionas mas recientes de android, necesitas mostrar una notificación para avisar al usuario que se estan enviando los datos de latitud y longitud, de otra forma no se van a enviar ya que no existe un servicio que corra por detras mandando esos datos mientras la app no esta siendo usada.

Chequea los limites de ejecucion en segundo plano

https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits

Deberias crear un servicio y hacer que ese servicio muestre una notificacion al usuario avisandole de lo que se esta ejecutando en segundo plano

> Nota: Si tu aplicación está orientada al nivel de API 26 o un nivel
>   superior, el sistema impone restricciones en la ejecución de servicios
>   en segundo plano cuando la aplicación misma no se encuentra en primer
>   plano. La mayoría de las veces, es mejor que tu aplicación use una
>   tarea programada.

Link: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background.html

Recorda que en android 10 ya no se puede obtener dicha información fuera de la app, ya que los permisos se dan cuando se usa la app y los datos recopilados son solo mientras la app se usa.